# Plotting the empirical cdf of a discrete random variable as a step function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following vector in Matlab

```
A=[0 0 0 1 1 0]
```

of dimension `nx1` with `n=6` where each element is a realization of a discrete random variable `X` with support from `0` to `n-1`, hence with support {0,1,2,3,4,5}.

The empirical cumulative distribution function is

F=0 for any x<0

F=4/6 for any 0<=x<1

F=1 for any x>=1

I want to plot F in Matlab with x-axis ranging from -10 to 10. The result should be a step function. Could you help me?

I have tried `cdfplot(A)` but it does not give a step function and the x-axis ranges from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`stairs`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html):

```
A = [0 0 0 1 1 0];                       %// data
values = unique([-10 A 10]);             %// obtain values where CDF should be computed
F = cumsum(histc(A, values))/numel(A);   %// compute CDF
stairs(values, F)                        %// do the plot
axis([min(values) max(values) -.2 1.2])  %// adjust axes
```

[image]